# Conversion of Erythrosine to Fluorescein

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, synthesis, home-experiment, organic-reduction, dye

I am a home-chemist and I love dyes. I recently got my hands on sodium salt of **erythrosine** (tetra-iodinated **fluorescein**). I want to convert erythrosine to fluorescein. I speculate that using dilute NaOH solution might cause formation of sodium iodide and tetra-hydroxylated fluorescein. How can I reduce the alcohol groups without affecting the carboxylic acid groups.

Is there any better way to convert erythrosine to fluorescein?

[image: Erythrosine]
[image: Fluorescein]

Comment: Would Sodium borohydride work?

Comment: @Safrad Faisal Most probably, sodium borohydride will reduce the carboxylic groups.